# Logstash - RabbitMQ connection Timeout error

Tags: rabbitmq, logstash, logstash-forwarder

I have installed logstash on 2 nodes to send the logs to RabbitMQ. SSL is configured on RabbitMQ listening 5671 port. I have configured both the logstash to push the logs to rabbitmq server on the 5671 port.

This is my configuration.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/messages"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
filter {
  grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:system_auth_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:system_auth_hostname} %{GREEDYDATA:command_issued}: %{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
        add_tag => "syslog"
  }
}
output {
    rabbitmq {
        exchange => "elasticsearch-exchange"
        exchange_type => "direct"
        key => "logstash-routing_key"
        ssl => true
        #verify_ssl => true
        ssl_certificate_password => 'Password'
        ssl_certificate_path => 'certfile'
        ssl_version => "TLSv1.2"
        host => "10.2.0.0"
        vhost => "es_vhost"
        durable => true
        persistent => true
        port => 5671
        user => "admin"
        password => "password"
        heartbeat => "5"
}
stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

This is the error I am getting in the logstash log.

```
{:timestamp=>"2017-12-26T07:22:32.708000+0000", :message=>"Pipeline aborted due to error", :exception=>java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException, :backtrace=>["com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(com/rabbitmq/utility/BlockingCell.java:77)", "com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(com/rabbitmq/utility/BlockingCell.java:111)", "com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(com/rabbitmq/utility/BlockingValueOrException.java:37)", "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(com/rabbitmq/client/impl/AMQChannel.java:367)", "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(com/rabbitmq/client/impl/AMQConnection.java:293)", "com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(com/rabbitmq/client/ConnectionFactory.java:648)", "com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(com/rabbitmq/client/ConnectionFactory.java:678)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:498)", "RUBY.new_connection_impl(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.15.0-java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:505)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281)", "RUBY.converting_rjc_exceptions_to_ruby(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.15.0-java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:467)", "RUBY.new_connection_impl(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.15.0-java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:500)", "RUBY.initialize(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.15.0-java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:136)", "RUBY.connect(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.15.0-java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:109)", "RUBY.connect(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.15.0-java/lib/march_hare.rb:20)", "RUBY.connect(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-mixin-rabbitmq_connection-4.1.1-java/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/rabbitmq_connection.rb:174)", "RUBY.connect!(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-mixin-rabbitmq_connection-4.1.1-java/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/rabbitmq_connection.rb:131)", "RUBY.register(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-rabbitmq-3.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/rabbitmq.rb:40)", "RUBY.register(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:75)", "RUBY.start_workers(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:181)", "org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613)", "RUBY.start_workers(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:181)", "RUBY.run(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:136)", "RUBY.start_pipeline(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/agent.rb:473)", "java.lang.Thread.run(java/lang/Thread.java:745)"], :level=>:error}
{:timestamp=>"2017-12-26T07:22:35.710000+0000", :message=>"stopping pipeline", :id=>"main"}
```

This is the error I am getting in RabbitMQ logs.

```
=INFO REPORT==== 27-Dec-2017::05:44:27 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.1228.0> (10.2.0.0:42187 -> 10.24.168.17:5601)

=WARNING REPORT==== 27-Dec-2017::05:44:35 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.1228.0> (10.2.0.0:42187 -> 10.24.168.17:5601):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
```

This is RabbitMQ conf

```
% This file managed by Puppet
% Template Path: rabbitmq/templates/rabbitmq.config
[
  {rabbit, [
    {cluster_nodes, {[rabbit@node01, rabbitmq@node02, rabbit@node03], disc}},
    {cluster_partition_handling, ignore},
    {tcp_listen_options,
         [binary,
         {packet,        raw},
         {reuseaddr,     true},
         {backlog,       128},
         {nodelay,       true},
         {exit_on_close, false}]
    },
    {default_user, <<"admin">>},
    {default_pass, <<"passowrd">>},
    {handshake_timeout, 60000},
    {tcp_listeners, []},
    {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
    {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ssl_cert/testca/cacert.pem"},
                {certfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ssl_cert/server/cert.pem"},
                {keyfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ssl_cert/server/key.pem"},
                {password,  "Password"},
                {verify,verify_peer},
                {versions, ['tlsv1.2']},
                {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}]},
    {ssl_handshake_timeout, 5000}
    {log_levels, [{autocluster, debug}, {connection, info}]}
  ]},
  {kernel, [

  ]},
  {rabbitmq_management, [
    {listener, [
      {port, 15672}
    ]}
  ]}
].
% EOF
```

I have even changed the SSL listener port to 5601 and tried just to make sure that this is not port conflict. I am hitting the wall everytime here.

Comment: Have you tried connecting without SSL/TLS? Just to sort out false options, try doing that, if connects normally, then it's probably a security channel issue

Comment: Without SSL/TLS, it's working just perfectly fine. And my requirement is to have a 2 way SSL configured.

Comment: Try also increasing `ssl_handshake_timeout` in RabbitMQ config. If that doesn't help, try enabling 1-way SSL first to figure out which side fails

Comment: Okay I will try it out.

Comment: Nope, no use in increasing the `ssl_handshake_timeout` value, also tried one-way SSL.

Comment: `=INFO REPORT==== 28-Dec-2017::05:30:52 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.5691.0> (10.2.0.0:40790 -> 10.2.0.0:5601)

=WARNING REPORT==== 28-Dec-2017::05:31:00 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.5691.0> (10.2.0.0:40790 -> 10.2.0.0:5601):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection`
This is error I am getting from RabbitMQ logs.

Comment: Try using `wireshark` to trace what's happening during TLS handshake. Unfortunately the error messages are often useless when you deal with TLS. The interesting messages will be the ones just before connection termination. Also, what version of RabbitMQ are you using?

Comment: I was able to find out why this was happening. I issued the following command to check as to which side we are having the problem with whether the Logstash or the RabbitMQ

`openssl s_server -accept 8443 /etc/rabbitmq/ssl_cert/client/cert.pem -key /etc/rabbitmq/ssl_cert/client/key.pem -CAfile /etc/rabbitmq/ssl_cert/testca/cacert.pem`

`openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443 -cert /etc/rabbitmq/ssl_cert/client/cert.pem -key /etc/rabbitmq/ssl_cert/client/key.pem -CAfile /etc/rabbitmq/ssl_cert/testca/cacert`

Comment: Got this error:

`Start Time: 1514452741
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 26 (unsupported certificate purpose)`

Comment: Now will regenerate the certificates and try once more.

Comment: @AlexBuyny I have regenerated the certifiactes and tried once again. I am getting the same error all over. I am using Rabbitmq 3.6.5 and Logstash 2.3.4

Answer (score 0):

There was a mismatch in hostname. I have resolved it by proving an FQDN in the `/etc/hosts` file. SSL is working fine now.